# Replacing " with \"

Tags: javascript, regex, json, string

I'm trying to replace all `"` with `\"` and parse string with JSON but browser throws an error `SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '\'`.

Below is code. String a is JSON.parsed well, but although I replace all `"` with `\"` in string b, so that it should be identical to string a, the parsing fails. I have the code in [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/vagax/2/edit).

```
var a = '[\"{\\"objects\\":[],\\"background\\":\\"#fff\\"}\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\"]';

var b = '["{\"objects\":[],\"background\":\"#fff\"}","","","","","","","","",""]';

// Replace " with \"
// Charcode 92 is \
b = b.replace('"', String.fromCharCode(92)+'"', "g");

a = JSON.parse(a);
console.log(a);
b = JSON.parse(b);
console.log(b);
```

Any idea, how I could string b parsed with JSON.parse? If I replace all `"` with `\"` manually, it parses well, but I'm seeking automated way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
b = b.replace(/"(?=[^\{]*\})/g, '\\"');
```

This will replace all the `"` within braces to `\"`.

The first string `a` becomes actually:

```
["{\"objects\":[],\"background\":\"#fff\"}","","","","","","","","",""]
```

And that's what you have to make `b` become, except that just after making the variable, it becomes:

```
["{"objects":[],"background":"#fff"}","","","","","","","","",""]
```

So you actually have to put some `\` back where they should be.

But since you are trying to parse JSON, you might be better off with:

```
b = JSON.stringify(b);
```

Comment: The string is JSON.stringified Fabric.js objects in array. The simple one works with your regexp, but a bit more complex fails: http://jsbin.com/vexuk/3/edit. Any idea why?

Comment: @Timo Yes, JS regexp is not good to parse JSON, as simple as that. There are nested braces in there, and to make matters worse, JS's regex are not equipped to deal with that. If it was PHP, perl, C# or something like that, it'd have been possible with regex. For example with [PCRE](http://regex101.com/r/tR3vO9). But unfortunately, JS regex doesn't handle recursion in regex...

Comment: So is there a generic solution?

Comment: @Timo Hmm, I'm not a pro at JS or JSON, but try `b = JSON.stringify(b);`. It might just work.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. It led me to the solution. I have stringified doubly. In the function where I stringified the "a bit more complex string", I had a line: `imgData[i] = JSON.stringify(canvas); imgData = JSON.stringify(imgData);` When I changed it to `imgData[i] = canvas; imgData = JSON.stringify(imgData);`, parsing string succeeded without regexps or similar.

Answer (score 5):

the point is using 2 `\`:

```
b = b.replace(/"/g,'\\"')
```

and the result is:

```
[\"{\"objects\":[],\"background\":\"#fff\"}\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\"]
```

as @isherwood, has said:

> To be more clear, the backslash is an escape character, so you need to
>   double it so there's an actual character behind the escape.

Comment: To be more clear, the backslash is an escape character, so you need to double it so there's an actual character behind the escape.

Comment: `b = b.replace(/"/g,"\\")` doesn't work: http://jsbin.com/vexuk/1/edit. Throws still `SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '\'`.

Comment: @isherwood: thanks, I added your great explanation to the answer.

Comment: @Timo: sorry body, something was missing, I changed my answer and add the result.